# create Hyperlink to open in browser not in android gmail app

Tags: android, html, browser, hyperlink, gmail

I am creating a link in HTML and sending to Gmail account. Now in Android Gmail app it opens in Gmail integrated browser, what should be added in link in HTML so that it should be open in browser not in app

**The link is coming from a website not from app**

Comment: Have you handled the [deeplink](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) ?

Comment: AFAIK gmail handles it, so it will open in the way it thinks it should open it.

Comment: I have created a simple HTML hyperlink nothing else

Comment: It would be great if you can tell me what extra we need to add in hyperlink to solve the issue

Comment: And I have use in .net application not android app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to force an HTML link to be opened with a specific app by changing the HTML link unless the domain you're linking to is yours and the specific app you want the link to be opened with is also yours.

However the user can change his/her settings in the Gmail app to open all links from all mail in the default browser instead of the integrated browser. To do this go to hamburger menu -> settings -> general settings -> untick open web links in Gmail.